# Does DotNetNuke 6 support Ajax Control Toolkit?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

Does anybody have successfully working module in DNN 6 with the Ajax Control Toolkit? 
My modules stopped working when we migrated from DNN 5.x to to 6.x.
Modules compile without errors but I am getting client side script error:

**'AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll'**

Seems like this is conflict with Telerik's controls, according to information that I have found. But I didn't find any info how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could work together, but you'll need do some modifications to the core of DNN.

Here the list of things to do:

- Check that you're using latest version of .Net 4.0 binaries of AjaxControlToolkit (I was able to let it work for DNN 6.0.1 with Telerik 2011.01.519 and ACT September 2011 v4.1.50927)
- Check that in your web.config you have assembly binding redirects for `System.Web.Extensions` and `System.Web.Extensions.Design` to the version 4.0
- Take DNN source package, find `Library\Framework\AJAX.cs`, locate method `AddScriptManager`, instantiation of RadScriptManager in it, for the version 6.0.1 look into line 54. Add one more property initializer:
  `EnableScriptCombine = false`. Compile it (in Release configuration, of course), take DotNetNuke.dll and drop into your DNN installation.

You should be done.

Credits goes to [Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-and-stylesheetmanager/known-issues-and-breaking-changes-radscriptmanager.aspx), despite it's stated there that it should work out of the box starting from 2010.1.625. Not sure, did I get them wrong, or they just reintroduced this bug.

P.S. DNN support [promises](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/203/postid/433679/scope/posts.aspx#433679) to release version 6.1.0 in November with updated Telerik controls, which should fix this issue, at least on their opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use older versions of the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit, but once they start requiring the `ToolkitScriptManager`, you're out of luck with DNN (though you'll be out of luck with *any* version of DNN, since there's not a way to override the type of `ScriptManager` it uses.

Starting with DNN 6, they use Telerik's `RadScriptManager`.  Previously, you could modify the core code to switch out for the `ToolkitScriptManager`, but now switching out might cause other issues.

Comment: Is there a way you can mix modules using ASP.NET AJAX and `RadScriptManager` in one installation of DNN6, or are we stuck with DNN5?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked with nuke 6.1 and the last version of jaxcontroltoolkit - still the same error.
It looks like it's not supported anymore. Sad:(

Comment: Strange, I upgraded to DNN 6.1.3 and my AJAXToolkit is working fine? You can see it on this page - http://www.pokerdiy.com/poker-league/lid/241/rods-sydney-poker-league.aspx  (note - I have not upgraded the AJAX Toolkit in some time!)