# AjaxExtender control tool kit not working in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

I am using dotnetnuke to build websites. when i tried to implement rating control of ajax extender tool kit, it shows some error and i'm not getting the preferred output. Not only in the case of rating control, but also for all types of controls in ajax tool kit. Is anybody know ajax extender control tool kit support dotnet nuke?

Comment: Have you seen this here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610380/does-dotnetnuke-6-support-ajax-control-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

This control used to work really well, but with all of the changes since around DNN 5.x and the conversion to .NET 3.5 I have not found a stable way of integrating it.

Comment: Only+one+instance+of+a+ScriptManager+can+be+added+to+the+page...this is the error showing

Answer (score 0):

if you have display problem (with the positioning of controls), put the extender in a div and set the position to relative for the DIV

Comment: Only+one+instance+of+a+ScriptManager+can+be+added+to+the+page...this is the error showing

Comment: do not put script manager control, instead use the below code in codebehind

DotNetNuke.Framework.AJAX.RegisterScriptManager()

Comment: This should be placed in the Load event of the control.

Comment: still its not working..i pasted the your code in the page load..this is my aspx code                                                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txt_control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1"  TargetControlID="txt_control" 
    WatermarkText="Type First Name Here"
 runat="server">
    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>